# Retrofit send multiple parameters in same name

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is the web URL:

```
mytasks/all/tasks?id=12&id=20&id=21&id=22&id=23&id=24
```

This is Retrofit API interface:

```
@GET("mytasks/all/tasks")
Call<Task> getAllTasks(@Query("id") List<String> taskIds);
```

I am getting a **bad URL** error.

Comment: is this url complete ? did u try hitting it from restclient ? is it giving expected response ?

Comment: yep i tried it from restclient (postman) it gave me the correct response.

Comment: @Lakshan did you solve the problem? How?

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach can help you, try:

```
@GET("mytasks/all/tasks")
Call<Task> getAllTasks(@Query("id[]") List<String> taskIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get a json array as result so you need to get your result as a list. And if your id's are integers you can pass Integer as task id.

```
@GET("mytasks/all/tasks")
Call<List<Task>> getTask(@Query("id") List<Integer> taskIds);
```

Comment: Task is my model inside that there is a array list.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:-

```
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@GET("branch/cart") Call<CartResponse> Carts(
        @Header("Authorization")String Authorization
        ,@Query("status[]") String status1
        ,@Query("page")int page
        ,@Query("status[]") String ... status
);
```